# How do chained routers work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, connection

**Straight to the point :**

- I have a computer (**PC1**) that is connected to a router (**R1**).
- **R1** is **private**. No one can access it **directly** execpt **PC1**.
- Router 2 (**R2**) is connected to **R1** by wire. **R2 is public**. So anyone can access this router.
- Only **R1** is connected to the modem...
- **PC1** works perfectly, so does **R1**.

> > **Problem :**
> >
> > **R2** keeps losing connection from **R1**. So people can't access internet properly.

**Questions :**

1. What **approach** should I use to find what causes the problem ?
2. How does chained routers work, I mean, how does **R1** decides how much "bandwidth" it gives to **R2**?

> > **PS :**
> >
> > I need to map a large region (well not that large, but still) and there are more chained routers : **R1** << **R2** << **R3** << etc.
> >
> > So figuring out the problem for the first two routers will help me fix the others.

I need a somewhat **general guideline** in fixing this problem. It wasn't me who chained those routers, so I don't know all the specifics. Throwing all that information in here would surely **complexify my question**. So I will keep it simple.

If needed, I will add more info!

Thanks!

SS

Comment: Normally, routers are chained like this unnecessarily, but here you are making the distinction between private and public routers.  Can you expand on what you mean by that?  Are you talking about wifi?  Are there different security controls in place?

Comment: Like I said, it's not my idea, but it goes like so :

**R1** is the main router. It is the only router that is connected to the **modem**. It is **private** because **no device other than PC1 can connect to it**. Now, **R2** is also connected to **R1**. So, **R1** is actually spliting the signal in two : first part goes to **PC1**, seconde goes to **R2**.

Comment: Differents passwords for **R1** and **R2**

Comment: yes, different wifi paswords

Comment: I think they over did it, I'm pretty sure it can simplified. It seems usless to me to have router (R1) that splits the connection (bandwidth) between **PC1** and and another router.

Comment: And is the intention here to keep things connecting to wifi on R1 separate from R2?  Because the way you are describing it, this would not be the case right now.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if their idea of splitting the connection really worked. Thanks for that part! But like I said, I'm really here to understand  **How does chained routers work and I mean, how does R1 decides how much "bandwidth" it gives to R2?** You're helping me a lot here. It's pretty simple really. **If I can cut the number of routers in half** and just **plug PC1 directly into the modem**, I'll do that. I just don't quite get **how the signal travels through multiples routers** and **how bandwidth is splitted when I have chained routers**

Comment: It is really a "best effort" type arrangement if there are no bandwidth controls.  So if someone on R2 is using lots of bandwidth, they will get the most.  If R1 and R2 are both using lots, then the bandwidth will be attempted to split evenly.  This doesn't explain the disconnects - that is more likely a misconfiguration.